# Laravel 5 | Redirecting multiple URLs to the same path

Tags: url, laravel, authentication, redirect, routes

I have a main authentication URL **auth/login** and I want that multiple matches like **/login** or **/authenticate** redirect to this one without writing a bunch of duplicate lines.

How can I do that?

Comment: there's no issue with duplicating a couple of lines, if they are more then put routes in array and loop over them... however, i don't recommend this if you care about seo

Comment: Got it, SEO is really important and maybe use such resource don't worth.

Answer (score 0):

Create a named route called "login" and use redirects for any other path you want. Use a 301 Redirect as in the following example to avoid "duplicate content" issues.

```
Route::get('auth/login', ['as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin']);

Route::get('login', function(){ Redirect::route('login', 301); });
Route::get('authenticate', function(){ Redirect::route('login', 301); });
```